# Lazily consuming log file lines in (concatenated) batches

Tags: haskell, file-io, lazy-evaluation

I have this function for lazily watching a log file...

```
follow :: Handle -> IO [String]
follow h = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
  catch (do line <- hGetLine h
            lines <- follow h
            return $ line : lines)
        (const (do threadDelay (1000 * 100)
                   follow h))
```

...which is great because it returns an infinite list which can be processed line-by-line as the log file is appended to, like so:

```
h <- openFile "test.log" ReadMode
ls <- follow h 
mapM_ putStrLn ls
```

But now I need to join some lines together before processing them. (Some log entries are xml split over multiple lines which I need to put back together). I tried the following to do just that, but it never terminates because `follow` never does, as I understand it.

```
h <- openFile "test.log" ReadMode
ls <- follow h 
mapM_ putStrLn (concatWhen (isPrefixOf "foo") ls)

concatWhen :: (String -> Bool) -> [String] -> [String]
concatWhen _ [] = []
concatWhen p as = let (xs, as') = span p as
                      (ys, rest) = break p as'
                   in (concat xs) : ys ++ (concatWhen p rest)
```

Is there a good way of doing this?  Do I need to do the line joining within `follow`, or is there a more elegant way that can operate on the string array returned by that function?

If it makes any difference, it is possible to determine if a line is the last of a group that needs concatenating by checking the contents.

Comment: By the way, lazy IO like this has many problems (primarily related to resource allocation), and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
concatWhen p (x:xs)
    | p x       = let (ys,zs) = span p xs in concat (x:ys) : concatWhen zs
    | otherwise = x : concatWhen p xs
concatWhen _ _  = []
```

should be lazy enough. But it has different semantics if the first line doesn't satisfy `p` :(
So you would need a wrapper

```
wrapConcatWhen p xxs@(x:_)
    | p x       = concatWhen p xxs
    | otherwise = "" : concatWhen p xxs
wrapConcatWhen _ _ = []
```

But, looking closer at it, your `concatWhen` should also be lazy enough, perhaps a bit less efficient due to the extra `break` which allocates some pair constructors if it isn't optimised out.

What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Actually, yes, it does half work - it just doesn't return a concatenated group until a line which does not match the predicate, which makes sense.  Stupidly I was only testing with matching lines. Thanks for making me take another look!  Lazy evaluation is marvellous :)